# How to apply contenteditable attribute in Pug

Tags: javascript, pug

Newbie questions!

How can we use contenteditable (html5) for td in pug? does pug support that? I couldn't find an example anywhere.

What's the best way to change text value in td to an textbox so users can edit?

Comment: It's possible, but the only items you should set content editable are `div` and `span`, in my opinion. `td` may cause some unexpected results. You can set the `div` as a child element of `td`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is `td(contenteditable)`

Longer answer:

First things first.
For user input better use `<input>` or `<textarea>`. You can append it into td on click event for example. After that set an equal value via power of Javascript, but it is another question)

The result of `td(contenteditable)` would be `<td contenteditable="contenteditable"></td>`, so if you need disable "mirroring" to get only `<td contenteditable></td>` You must setup proper doctype on the first place with `doctype` or `doctype html`. That results into `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<td contenteditable></td>`.

Check how result HTML changes with doctype and without, using this code at https://pug.vercel.app/

```
doctype
html
  table
    tr
      td(contenteditable)
```

Also it can conflict with your framework setup related to https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/237
But using `contenteditable` itself can be tricky with different browsers.

Comment: doesn't work because pug is adding the attribute as `contenteditable="contenteditable"` which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the string `true` as the `contenteditable` value in *pug*:

```
div(contenteditable='true') some text
```

Because pug doesn't know how to do value-less attributes, as it just copies the attribute name as its own value, which the browser considers invalid and completely ignores the attribute (for certain ones).